# IE 9/8 breaks my div into 2 divs of same id and separates elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Hey I just made a landing page and it looks fine on chrome

http://www.advicestudents.ro/tommy/homepage/homepage_v1/homepage.html

well the `CRT_abs` div that holds the heading subtitle and button duplicates on IE 9 and 8 it goes `CRT_abs` for the text and `CRT_abs` for the button same goes for the H1 holder DIV !

Dose anyone understands why this happens?

HTML code for holder :

```
                <a href="#"><div id="h1" style="margin-top:-3px;">
                <img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="CRT_abs" style="text-align: center;width: 711px;left: 139px;top: 219px;padding: 0px;">
                    <div class="CRT_title_s_i CRT_white" style="line-height:16px; font-size:16px; text-transform: none; margin-bottom: 8px;">
                        Fall Outerwear
                    </div>
                    <div class="CRT_gills  CRT_white" style=" font-family:ITCCaslon224W01-BookIt;font-size:40px; line-height:40px; margin-bottom: 9px; letter-spacing:1px;">
                        THE WARM UP
                    </div>
                    <div class="CRT_subtitle CRT_white" style="font-size:14px; margin-bottom: 12px;">
                        The perfect coat for every occasion,
                        <br />
                        from vintage bomber to collegiate dufﬂe.
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="CRT_btn_white">SHOP OUTERWEAR <span class="CRT_f18 CRT_gills">&rsaquo;</span></a>
                </div>
            </div></a>
```

so some CSS styleing is already inline coded into the HTML as you can see + the Position:absolute on the CRT_abs. I think thats all

Comment: post code, not a link

Comment: ha ha ha.. that looks so funny... :)

Comment: try adding a div tag to `SHOP OUTERWEAR` btn

Comment: Found the problem, the first <a> tag that wraps around the main holder is the problem if I move that around the image it will work

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you were trying to nest `<a>` elements. That's not allowed. A [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) would have picked that up for you.

Comment: tryed with a validator but all that it sayd it was that the end tag for the <a> tag was wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the first link tag that was wraping the whole main div, moved it to wrap only the image so i got the same effect and no more buggs. The buttons have the right possition now.